# No logging and compression on newly created table

Tags: oracle

I created a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE pull_dtl
(
    source_schema VARCHAR2(4000),
    source_tablename VARCHAR2(4000),
    db_link VARCHAR2(4000),
    dest_schema VARCHAR2(4000),
    dest_tablename VARCHAR2(4000),
    dest_tablespace VARCHAR2(4000)
)
```

How do I make it "no logging" and I need to "compress" it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable `NOLOGGING`, run the following query

```
ALTER TABLE pull_dtl NOLOGGING;
```

See [Table Compression Enhancements in Oracle Database](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/table-compression-enhancements-11gr1.php) for compression options.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea on how to compress the table?

Comment: ALTER TABLE staging_pull_dtl COMPRESS; Got it now. Thank you